# S3 event notification only sends metadata to SQS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

Trying to understanding about SQS.

I recently enabled an S3 event to sync data form S3 to SQS. When I upload a file (some plain text data) to S3 I only see metadata (of the file uploaded to S3) in the SQS queue and not the actual data in the file.

Below is response I get from SQS cli.

```
{
"Messages": [{
    "Body": "{\"Records\":[{\"eventVersion\":\"2.1\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:s3\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-west-2\",\"eventTime\":\"2019-02-03T04:20:52.812Z\",\"eventName\":\"ObjectCreated:Put\",\"userIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"AWS:AROAJPPH7T6UMTQNWQDV4:email@email.com\"},\"requestParameters\":{\"sourceIPAddress\":\"***.***.95.237\"},\"responseElements\":{\"x-amz-request-id\":\"D0FBEB5DD148EC84\",\"x-amz-id-2\":\"F7q+hW5hb6f02J42gT1wWDWjAp2wuQ3ojio1n2Bz/jZCS+e+6/zjkYsUfRNB59dqH61p67rPJDU=\"},\"s3\":{\"s3SchemaVersion\":\"1.0\",\"configurationId\":\"SQS-hops-mab-new-hotelids\",\"bucket\":{\"name\":\"bukcet-name\",\"ownerIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"A3HAX2MIKOSGAO\"},\"arn\":\"arn:aws:s3:::bukcet-name\"},\"object\":{\"key\":\"prefix/data_file\",\"size\":80,\"eTag\":\"b10063d01db20998584a425f0fa77a29\",\"sequencer\":\"005C566C24C2E9A48A\"}}}]}",
    "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBGIumiawoH/pKK5deThbTsCuZ8bWlgF/p8qiL1VTrDqpkUkVxWUxlzMftEtfRzqFZKx+nyUCjuSb50Oicd7hq51LUexOro0+GTVtQsxJlEJ9RaxIk+7/Ia1Ac7ox2G4Mt1nnFBDiEsiPgwYwbQe0fAz1EFiI3QZuZtOdyPNFAIaObPJGhF591IwSA6xhIqgHYJwo5pvw/axVCd05Ex34wg/TFIN9Ha4RVUSDWFXpBmPtM/1V6Ek6HP/Ag0Ps3HKhG1KNOFUjq0mv6bGqaXI/HuxCGitj3uk0xX25y0lT+RFomWcDyKpbmfm2fue8StABrKE7sm/inc1Zbd/4qKFTNUdPqQVqIr3s55plAPDXGvNiXBx4O7FkrE1jrxHBeONMRrlYHe2/KeL0WaITYu3dxNw==",
    "MD5OfBody": "0c04939f7c38ff3f9992ef911b514ed7",
    "MessageId": "f7fcb7da-66cb-4a59-acf0-79f75e9a60ce"
}]
```

}

Below is the metadata in the above **Body** section.

```
{
"Records": [{
    "eventVersion": "2.1",
    "eventSource": "aws:s3",
    "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
    "eventTime": "2019-02-04T01:00:31.166Z",
    "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
    "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AROAJPPH7T6UMTQNWQDV4:email@****.com"
    },
    "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "***.***.95.237"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "24703DDF194A1F7E",
        "x-amz-id-2": "wwpJeU6B3yZT7qaB7imsucsaM8y1hpFBi14POL4L1/2C1/CoBRkdHLgIOPzyy85a3RPJQFfE9Ys="
    },
    "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "SQS-name",
        "bucket": {
            "name": "bucket-name",
            "ownerIdentity": {
                "principalId": "A3HAX2MIKOSGAO"
            },
            "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        },
        "object": {
            "key": "prefix/datafile",
            "size": 80,
            "eTag": "b10063d01db20998584a425f0fa77a29",
            "sequencer": "005C578EAF156E8A91"
        }
    }
}]
```

}

**Doesn't the S3 event notification send the actual data to SQS? Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct SQS will only get the metadata of S3 object being created/modified or based on notification event. Regardless of the destination type you choose, S3 notification structure is same for all destinations. S3 object could be anything audio, video or some huge JSON file. SQS has its [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html) and it cannot always receive actual S3 object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would've been good if aws doc specifies this point, didn't see anywhere in the doc. Thanks for the link to limitations of SQS.

Comment: Indeed it is documented. Regardless of the destination type you choose, S3 notification structure is same for all destinations. You can find more info on S3 event message structure [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html)

Comment: Cool. I clearly overlooked some concepts here. Thanks.